# Delayed transformations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a simple DHTML application, nothing strange: I have around 500 balls colliding with each other with different speeds and by clicking a button they stack based on their velocities creating a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution(but that's another talk).
[image: to pass from here]

[image: to here]

Well, for switching from the first to the second case I'm changing every single x and y coordinate for every single ball, to move them and pile them in that way.
Now, my question is: is it possible to have a sort of an animation in which balls from the first chaotic case, instead of jumping into the chart-configuration in one frame(as soon as the button gets clicked), gradually stack on top of each other in a much fancier and "graphical" animation? For example with transitions or transformations, but I couldn't manage to find a way to do that... I'm quite new to programming.
By the way, here's the full code:

FULL CODE:

```js
class Ball {
    
    constructor(x, y, dx, dy, radius, color){
        this.radius = radius;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;

        // mass is that of a sphere as opposed to circle
        // it *does* make a difference in how realistic it looks
        this.mass = this.radius * this.radius * this.radius;
        this.color = color;
    };    

    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(Math.round(this.x), Math.round(this.y), this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
       // ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    };

    speed() {
        // magnitude of velocity vector
        return Math.sqrt(this.dx * this.dx + this.dy * this.dy);
    };
    angle() {
        // velocity's angle with the x axis
        return Math.atan2(this.dy, this.dx);
    };
    onGround() {
        return (this.y + this.radius >= canvas.height)
    };
};

//FUNCTIONS

//will remove
function randomColor() {
    let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 127;
    let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 127;
    let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 127;

    // dim down the small balls
    if (!bigBalls){
        red *= 0.65
        green *= 0.65
        blue *= 0.65
    }

    let rc = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
    return rc;
}

function randomX() {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    if (x < 30) {
        x = 30;
    } else if (x + 30 > canvas.width) {
        x = canvas.width - 30;
    }
    return x;
}

function randomY() {
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
    if (y < 30) {
        y = 30;
    } else if (y + 30 > canvas.height) {
        y = canvas.height - 30;
    }
    return y;
}

//will remove
function randomRadius() {
    if (bigBalls) {
        let r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 + 20);
        return r;
    } else {
        let r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2 + 2);
        //let r = 5;
        return r;
    }
}

//will remove
function randomDx() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 - 4);
    return r;
}

//will remove
function randomDy() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 - 3);
    return r;
}

function distanceNextFrame(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt((a.x + a.dx - b.x - b.dx)**2 + (a.y + a.dy - b.y - b.dy)**2) - a.radius - b.radius;
}

function distance(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt((a.x - b.x)**2 + (a.y - b.y)**2);
}

let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let objArray = [];
let probArray = [];
let paused = false;
let bumped = false;

let leftHeld = false;
let upHeld = false;
let rightHeld = false;
let downHeld = false;
let arrowControlSpeed = .25;

let gravityOn = false;

let clearCanv = true;

let bigBalls = false;

let lastTime = (new Date()).getTime();
let currentTime = 0;
let dt = 0;

let numStartingSmallBalls = 500;
let numStartingBigBalls = 0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);

function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function keyDownHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 80) { // p
        paused = !paused;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 82) { // r
        objArray = [];
    } else if (event.keyCode == 75) { // k
        clearCanv = !clearCanv;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 88) { // x
        bigBalls = !bigBalls;
    }
}



function canvasBackground() {
    canvas.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(215, 235, 240)";
}

function wallCollision(ball) {
    if (ball.x - ball.radius + ball.dx < 0 ||
        ball.x + ball.radius + ball.dx > canvas.width) {
        ball.dx *= -1;
    }
    if (ball.y - ball.radius + ball.dy < 0 ||
        ball.y + ball.radius + ball.dy > canvas.height) {
        ball.dy *= -1;
    }
    if (ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height) {
        ball.y = canvas.height - ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.y - ball.radius < 0) {
        ball.y = ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.x + ball.radius > canvas.width) {
        ball.x = canvas.width - ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.x - ball.radius < 0) {
        ball.x = ball.radius;
    }    
}

function ballCollision() {
    for (let i=0; i<objArray.length-1; i++) {
        for (let j=i+1; j<objArray.length; j++) {
            let ob1 = objArray[i]
            let ob2 = objArray[j]
            let dist = distance(ob1, ob2)

            if (dist < ob1.radius + ob2.radius) {              
                let theta1 = ob1.angle();
                let theta2 = ob2.angle();
                let phi = Math.atan2(ob2.y - ob1.y, ob2.x - ob1.x);
                let m1 = ob1.mass;
                let m2 = ob2.mass;
                let v1 = ob1.speed();
                let v2 = ob2.speed();

                let dx1F = (v1 * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (m1-m2) + 2*m2*v2*Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.cos(phi) + v1*Math.sin(theta1-phi) * Math.cos(phi+Math.PI/2);
                let dy1F = (v1 * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (m1-m2) + 2*m2*v2*Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.sin(phi) + v1*Math.sin(theta1-phi) * Math.sin(phi+Math.PI/2);
                let dx2F = (v2 * Math.cos(theta2 - phi) * (m2-m1) + 2*m1*v1*Math.cos(theta1 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.cos(phi) + v2*Math.sin(theta2-phi) * Math.cos(phi+Math.PI/2);
                let dy2F = (v2 * Math.cos(theta2 - phi) * (m2-m1) + 2*m1*v1*Math.cos(theta1 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.sin(phi) + v2*Math.sin(theta2-phi) * Math.sin(phi+Math.PI/2);

                ob1.dx = dx1F;                
                ob1.dy = dy1F;                
                ob2.dx = dx2F;                
                ob2.dy = dy2F;

              /*  if(ob1.speed() * 160 < 400)
                    ob1.color = 'lightblue';
                else if(ob1.speed() * 160 > 800)
                    ob1.color = 'red';
                else
                    ob1.color = 'orange';

                if(ob2.speed() * 160 < 400)
                    ob2.color = 'lightblue';
                else if(ob2.speed() * 160 > 800)
                    ob2.color = 'red';
                else
                    ob2.color = 'orange';*/
          
                staticCollision(ob1, ob2);
                
            }            
        }
        wallCollision(objArray[i]);
    }

    if (objArray.length > 0)
        wallCollision(objArray[objArray.length - 1])
}

function staticCollision(ob1, ob2, emergency = false)
{
    let overlap = ob1.radius + ob2.radius - distance(ob1, ob2);
    let smallerObject = ob1.radius < ob2.radius ? ob1 : ob2;
    let biggerObject = ob1.radius > ob2.radius ? ob1 : ob2;

    // When things go normally, this line does not execute.
    // "Emergency" is when staticCollision has run, but the collision
    // still hasn't been resolved. Which implies that one of the objects
    // is likely being jammed against a corner, so we must now move the OTHER one instead.
    // in other words: this line basically swaps the "little guy" role, because
    // the actual little guy can't be moved away due to being blocked by the wall.
    if (emergency) [smallerObject, biggerObject] = [biggerObject, smallerObject]
    
    let theta = Math.atan2((biggerObject.y - smallerObject.y), (biggerObject.x - smallerObject.x));
    smallerObject.x -= overlap * Math.cos(theta);
    smallerObject.y -= overlap * Math.sin(theta); 

    if (distance(ob1, ob2) < ob1.radius + ob2.radius) {
        // we don't want to be stuck in an infinite emergency.
        // so if we have already run one emergency round; just ignore the problem.
        if (!emergency) staticCollision(ob1, ob2, true)
    }
}

function moveObjects() {
    for (let i=0; i<objArray.length; i++) {
        let ob = objArray[i];
        ob.x += ob.dx * 1;
        ob.y += ob.dy * 1;
    }    
}

function drawObjects() {
    for (let obj in objArray) {
        objArray[obj].draw();
    }
}

let begin = true;
let temperature;

document.getElementById("temp").oninput = function()
{
    temperature = parseInt(document.getElementById("temp").value);
    generateBalls(temperature);
}

function drawChart() 
{
    let index = 0 
    let cx = 10 , cy;
    for(let i = 0; i < 59; i++) {
        cy = canvas.height - 6;
        if(probArray[i] != 0) {
            n = 0;
            while(n < probArray[i]) {
                objArray[index + n].x = cx;
                objArray[index + n].y = cy;
                cy -= 12;
                n++;
            }
            index += n;
        }
        cx += 20;
    }
    chart = !chart;
}

function draw() {
    
    /*currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    dt = (currentTime - lastTime) / 1000; // delta time in seconds
    
    // dirty and lazy solution
    // instead of scaling down every velocity vector
    // we decrease the speed of time
    dt *= 20;*/

    if(begin) {
        generateBalls(300);
        begin = false;
    }

    //work in progress
    if(chart) {    
        drawChart();
    }

    if (clearCanv) clearCanvas();
    canvasBackground();
    
    if (!paused) {
        moveObjects();
        ballCollision();
    }
    
    drawObjects();
    
    lastTime = currentTime;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

//work in progress
function setColor(vel)
{
    let red = 255, green = 255, blue = 255;
    let rc;
    green /= (vel * 0.001);
    blue /= (vel * 0.01);
    return rc = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";

}

let N = 550;
let m = 2.66e-26;
let T = 5;
let dV = 50;
let k = 1.38e-23;
let v = 50;
let balls;
let angolox;
let vel;
let color;


function generateBalls(T)
{
    paused = false;
    v = 50;

    objArray = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < 59; i++) 
    { //each 50m/s, with dv = 50, until 2000m/s

    //molecules number between v and v+50
    probArray[i] = Math.floor(4 * Math.PI * N * (((m) / (2 * Math.PI * k * T))**1.5) * (v**2) * Math.exp((-m) / (2 * k * T) * (v**2)) * dV);
        v += 50;
    }

    v = 50;
    let l;

    for(let i = 0; i < 59; i++)
    {
        let n = 0;
        balls = 0;
        while(n < probArray[i]) 
        {
            angolox = ((Math.random() * 360) * Math.PI) / 180; //converted in radians;
            vel = Math.round((Math.random() * 50) + v) / 160; 
            if(vel * 160 < 400)
                color = 'lightblue';
            else if(vel * 160 > 800)
                color = 'red';
            else
                color = 'orange';
            l = objArray.length;
            objArray[objArray.length] = new Ball(randomX(), randomY(), Math.cos(angolox) * vel, Math.sin(angolox) * vel, 5, color);
            balls++;
            n++;
        }
    v += 50;
    }
}

let chart = false

function drawChart_bool() {
    chart = !chart;
    paused = !paused;
}

draw();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: khaki;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Ubuntu Mono;
  }

  #title {
    color: black;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px;
  }

  #balls {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

  #myCanvas {
    margin-top: -20px;
  }

  section.footer {
    color: black;
    font-family: Ubuntu Mono;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: small;
  }
  #disclaimer {
    font-size: 74%;
    color: gray;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>2d collision</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gas.css">
</head>
<body style="text-align: center">
  
    <canvas onload="generateBalls()" id="myCanvas" width="1225%" height="500" style="border:1px solid black; margin-top: 10px;"></canvas>
  

    <p>
      <input type="range" min="50" max="2050" value="300" step="100" id="temp">
      <input type="button" onclick="drawChart_bool()">
      <strong>[K]</strong> to toggle clearCanvas(); <br>
      <strong>[P]</strong>: pause/unpause || <strong>[R]</strong>: [RESET]
    </p>

    <div id="disclaimer" align="center" style="word-break: break-word; width: 350px; display:inline-block;">

      <p>
        Make sure to press a few buttons and play around.<br>Made with pure javascript.
      </p>

    </div>

  </section>
</body>
<script src="gas.js"></script>
</html>
```

FUNCTION I USE TO DRAW CHART(objArray is an ascending ordered one, based on speeds)

```js
function drawChart() 
{
    let index = 0 
    let cx = 10 , cy;
    for(let i = 0; i < 59; i++) {
        cy = canvas.height - 6;
        if(probArray[i] != 0) {
            n = 0;
            while(n < probArray[i]) {
                objArray[index + n].x = cx;
                objArray[index + n].y = cy;
                cy -= 12;
                n++;
            }
            index += n;
        }
        cx += 20;
    }
    chart = !chart;
}
```

FUNCTION I USE TO GENERATE BALLS:

```js
function generateBalls(T)
{
    paused = false;
    v = 50;

    objArray = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < 59; i++) 
    { //each 50m/s, with dv = 50, until 2000m/s

    //molecules number between v and v+50
    probArray[i] = Math.floor(4 * Math.PI * N * (((m) / (2 * Math.PI * k * T))**1.5) * (v**2) * Math.exp((-m) / (2 * k * T) * (v**2)) * dV);
        v += 50;
    }

    v = 50;
    let l;

    for(let i = 0; i < 59; i++)
    {
        let n = 0;
        balls = 0;
        while(n < probArray[i]) 
        {
            angolox = ((Math.random() * 360) * Math.PI) / 180; //converted in radians;
            vel = Math.round((Math.random() * 50) + v) / 160; 
            if(vel * 160 < 400)
                color = 'lightblue';
            else if(vel * 160 > 800)
                color = 'red';
            else
                color = 'orange';
            l = objArray.length;
            objArray[objArray.length] = new Ball(randomX(), randomY(), Math.cos(angolox) * vel, Math.sin(angolox) * vel, 5, color);
            balls++;
            n++;
        }
    v += 50;
    }
}
```

Heartfelt thanks in advance for any answer,
Greg.

Comment: There are quite a few options, most obvious is using `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @RoboRobok and how could I use that? what should the callback function be? Do you want me to upload my code?

Comment: It depends if you wan to animate via CSS or JavaScript. I usually prefer to animate via CSS. In your case, you could have transition on `left` and `top` property and then in your `setTimeout()` you would set the `left` and `top` property to appropriate position.

Comment: Try to help us help you by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we can probably help yhou get there.

Comment: @Yishmeray sure, I uploaded full code in a hidden snippet and the two main functions under consideration, which are generateBalls() and drawChart().

Comment: @RoboRobok but the deal is I wouldn't know how and where to insert the setTimeout() in my drawChart() function... by the way I uploaded the code so you can take a look too.

Comment: Okay, so you are using canvas. Cool. You would need to store two sets of coords for each ball that is supposed to move. That would be its destination and its current position. You always draw the current position. It's up to you where you put your animating code, you can end up without using setTimeout at all. The key is to set ball's current position accordingly, where and when you want it to be in certain position.

Comment: @RoboRobok so you told me I could change balls positions with CSS, but how is it possible to change a js object with CSS?

Comment: That would be if you didn't use canvas. But with the numerous balls you use here, canvas may actually be a better solution. Animating so many elements in CSS can lead to low FPS.

Comment: It would be best if you could draw what kind of animation you want to achieve. But let me tell you that: it's not a trivial task.

Comment: @RoboRobok and how could I implement transitions similar to CSS ones in canvas? I'm feeling so dumb, but as I said before my experience in coding is really poor... thanks for helping me!!

Comment: If you just want to have it done, consider using some library to animate on canvas. If you also want to learn and make it yourself, it requires some programming skills I'm afraid, as there are quite a few algorithmic patterns needed.

Comment: @RoboRobok alright, so you're telling me that with some libraries I can implement transitions for objects in javascript? And do you know some of them?

Comment: No, I haven't used any of those, but I googled for "javascript canvas animate library" and it shows some. Or maybe you could even find a library for animated charts that does have the type of chart you're looking for?